# Get list of dates for first week of current month in C#

Tags: c#

I have the below code which I am working around the list of dates for the first week in the current month.

```
 public static List<DateTime> GetDates(int year, int month)
{
   return Enumerable.Range(1, DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month))  
                    .Select(day => new DateTime(year, month, day)) 
                    .ToList(); 
}
```

But the issue is that I have getting all the dates for the current month.

What I want to achieve is the following:

```
Day: SUN, MON, TUE, WED, THU, FRI, SAT
Date 1, 2, 3, 5, 6..
```

How can I achieve this in C# ?

**Using this:**

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
            int currentDayOfWeek = (int) today.DayOfWeek;
            DateTime sunday = today.AddDays(-currentDayOfWeek);
            DateTime monday = sunday.AddDays(1);
            // If we started on Sunday, we should actually have gone *back*
            // 6 days instead of forward 1...
            if (currentDayOfWeek == 0)
            {
                monday = monday.AddDays(-7);
            }
            var dates = Enumerable.Range(0, 6).Select(days => monday.AddDays(days)).ToList();


            foreach (var date in dates) {
            Console.WriteLine(date);
            }
```

I managed to get the for the current week. But how can I get the day also?

The output is:

```
04.05.2020 00:00:00
05.05.2020 00:00:00
06.05.2020 00:00:00
07.05.2020 00:00:00
08.05.2020 00:00:00
09.05.2020 00:00:00
```

I want my ouput to be:

MON - 04.05.2020
TUE - 05.05.2020

Comment: You could use ```.Take(7)``` to get the first 7 days. Does that help?

Comment: define "first week": do the weeks in the locale you're programming for start with the first, or monday, sunday, saturday? and do you mean "first *full* week", or would you truncate?

Comment: Take(7) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take

Comment: What is your definition of the first week? The first 7 days, or the first whole week (by some country-specific definition of when a week starts)

Comment: You explicitly asked for `DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month)` number of days, if you only wanted 7, why not just ask for 7?

Comment: @Shawn: I managed to get the for the current week. But how can I get the day also?

Comment: Should week start on Sunday? (I assume yes.), and if 1st of current month is let's say Wednesday, does the first week start on the first Sunday after this?

Comment: @JonasHøgh: I managed to get the for the current week. But how can I get the day also?

Comment: The week should always start on Monday

Comment: We don't know what "the the" in "get the the for the current week" means. Can you show what you got, and what you wanted, instead?

Comment: @Badshah03 What about ```.SkipWhile(z => z.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Monday).Take(7)``` ?

Comment: At this time you should realize that your question is vague. You need to be more explicit in what you want. A good example of what you got, an example of what you wanted instead, and a textual description about what is wrong with what you got, goes a long way.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: I got the following- 

`04.05.2020 00:00:00
05.05.2020 00:00:00
06.05.2020 00:00:00
07.05.2020 00:00:00
08.05.2020 00:00:00
09.05.2020 00:00:00`

I want to have like two separate properties, one for day and date.

Comment: Try `Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("ddd dd.MM.yyyy"));`

Comment: Also, `DayOfWeek dayName = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.GetDayOfWeek(d);`

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: Nope. it does not do the trick

Comment: So what **did** my statement print then? Please get into the habit of explaining what you got and what you wanted, instead of just "Nope, not that". This is akin to "I'm not going to tell you what I want but I'm going to tell you when I see it, so please start churning out all possible combinations of everything you know so that I can look at them all and spot the one I want". I'm guessing what you want is `Console.WriteLine($"{date.DayOfWeek.ToString().Substring(0, 3).ToUpper()} - {date:dd.MM.yyyy}");` `.ToString("ddd")` will produce day of week, but it might be lowercase, and end with a dot.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`Enumerable.Take`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take?view=netcore-3.1) to get the first week (which corresponds to the first 7 items) of the returned list.

```
Enumerable.Range(1, DateTime.DaysInMonth(2020, 5))
                    .Select(day => new DateTime(2020, 5, day))
                    .Take(7)
                    .ToList();
```

Since you've stated that the first week should actually start on monday, you can modify the query using [`Enumerable.SkipWhile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skipwhile?view=netcore-3.1) to skip the days until you found the first correct date.

```
Enumerable.Range(1, DateTime.DaysInMonth(2020, 5))
                    .Select(day => new DateTime(2020, 5, day))
                    .SkipWhile(z => z.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Monday)
                    .Take(7)
                    .ToList();
```

---

Regarding your comment:

Using the [`ddd` formatter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings?redirectedfrom=MSDN#dddSpecifier) you can get the short names of the days. 
`string shortName = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddd");`

Comment: Nice workaround. How can I get the day also? Like MON, TUE, WED, etc..

Comment: You can fetch the first day of week from `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek`